# How does a site add multiple mages with only one src link?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I have come across an article on [iskysoft.com](https://www.iskysoft.com/online-video/youtube-search-not-working.htmlhttp://)
and in there header just before the search bar they have three links that have an image displayed - facebook, twitter and google+.
here is a screenshot[image]

When we look at the HTML part of it we see that there is no src link for the images

```
<p class="share_Btn">
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/iskysoft" class="facebook_bottom"></a>
 <a href="http://twitter.com/iskysoft" class="twitter_bottom"></a>
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/+iskysoft/" class="google_bottom"></a>
</p>
```

Then in the CSS there is only one link to an src

```
.share_Btn a{ display:inline-block; background:url(images/share_icon_small.png)
 no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; margin-right:12px; float:left;}

.share_Btn a.facebook_bottom{ background-position:0 0;}
.share_Btn a.twitter_bottom{ background-position:0 -28px;}
.share_Btn a.google_bottom{ background-position:0 -56px;}
```

so how to they get the three different images to display.

I am asking this question because I want to build a site with links to social networking and would rather use this method if I can understand it.

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried looking at the image directly?

Comment: they use a `background-image` instead of a `img` item. additional they use a css image sprite.

Comment: These are called `sprite images`

Comment: I could not look at the image directly as you can not right click and go view image, I tried typing in the url to the image but the server declined, Never knew it was called an image sprite. Thank you.